# Rcpp: I want a function to read a DataFrame, why is it possible to read a charactor vector and handle it as factor?

Tags: c++, r, types, dataframe, rcpp

Here is a minimal example:

```
// Enable C++11 via this plugin
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
/**
 * Wrapper function for testFunc
 */
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void testFunc(DataFrame vars_ ) {
  cout << "Type of vars_ " << TYPEOF(vars_) << endl;
  DataFrame vars = clone(vars_);
  CharacterVector out(vars_.nrows());
  vector<string>  varsV(vars_.nrows());
  vector<int> varsVInt(vars_.nrows());

  //Matrix is filled with input, Types are set to string
  for (int i = 0 ; i< vars_.size(); i++){

    if(TYPEOF(vars_[i])==STRSXP) {

      varsV=Rcpp::as<std::vector<string> > (vars_[i]);
      cout << "Type of the column " << i << " of the input data.frame is String."  << endl;

      for(int j=0; j<vars_.nrows(); j++){
        cout << "varsV["<<j<<"] "<<varsV[j] << endl;
      }

    }

    if(TYPEOF(vars_[i])==INTSXP) {

      cout << "Type of the column " << i << " of the input data.frame is Int/Factor."  << endl;
      varsVInt = Rcpp::as<std::vector<int> > (vars_[i]);

      if(varsVInt.size()>0)
      {

        for(int j=0; j<vars_.nrows(); j++){
          varsV[j]=to_string(varsVInt[j]);//Copy the vector to the string
          cout << "varsV["<<j<<"] "<<varsV[j] << endl;
        } // end for

      } //end if

    } // end if 

  } // endfor

}
```

**Execute Code:**

```
ID <- c("0","1","2")
NAME2 <- c("Milla", "Milla","Miller")

dfString <-data.frame(ID,NAME2, stringsAsFactors=F)

################# test function

A = testFunc(as.data.frame(dfString[,2],stringsAsFactors=F))
B = testFunc(as.data.frame(dfString[,2]))
```

**Call:**

```
A = testFunc(as.data.frame(dfString[,2],stringsAsFactors=F))
```

**Output:**

```
Type of vars_ 19
Type of the column 0 of the input data.frame is String.
varsV[0] Milla
varsV[1] Milla
varsV[2] Miller
```

**Call:**

```
B = testFunc(as.data.frame(dfString[,2]))
```

**Output:**

```
Type of vars_ 19
Type of the column 0 of the input data.frame is Int/Factor.
varsV[0] 1
varsV[1] 1
varsV[2] 2
```

In `void testFunc(DataFrame vars_ )` I expect an `Rcpp::DataFrame`, however if I paste a column of a `data.frame`, which is of class `character`, then it is also read without throwing an error, since the type seems the same (type 19). This `character vector` is handled a `factor`, see output.

Is there a way to force the right type (= `Rcpp::DataFrame`)? I don't want the user of the function accidentally paste the wrong type.

Comment: In both "A" and "B" calls of `testFunc` a single column "data.frame" is passed as argument since you coerced it to one. What are you willing to do? Are you trying to avoid "factor"s? If you want to coerce "factor" input to `STRSXP` use `asCharacterFactor('SEXP')`. Also `TYPEOF == 19` is, in general, a "list" (on which "data.frame" is built) -- it does not check if it is the _`class`_ "data.frame"

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid "factor", to get the original class/type of the columns of the data.frame. I would like the user to input character, integer or float columns. The user should be free to input one of these types. In my function I want to process the columns according to its type: `if(TYPEOF(vars_[i])==...`